# ubuntu software centre empty error after fresh os installation

Tags: software-center

after fresh new installation of 16.04.1 the ubuntu software centre is empty 
... does not show any software at all !
 [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySwbH.png)
and also [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jnr9g.png) controls are missing

howto recover ?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` or wait till it runs by itself.

Comment: yes ,  clearing  ~/.local/share/gnome-software  works .... I used commands:      $ killall gnome-software
    $ rm -r ~/.local/share/gnome-software       and rerun the software

Comment: it is Gnome GUI error   !!!!!  ......   NOT  command line packager  ......  so no use to run        " sudo apt update"